# How to solve CS1503 converting method group to object

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(GameHandler.Start);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

}
```

Can anyone tell me why there comes an error:
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'
I am confused cause the scripts should run well

Thank in advance for any help

Comment: You have tried to send a method, to something that outputs data, the method has no response, so what exactly were you expecting it to put in the debug log?

Comment: especially you are kind of recursive trying to call the same method? ^^ Did you mean something like `Debug.Log(nameof(GameHandler.Start));` ?

Comment: @derHugo yes it should be thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to make your log output a string. C# interprets it as a method group without the `"`.

Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("GameHandler.Start");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

}
```